# Keras Pretrained Model Traceback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When running this line:

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor, pooling=None, classes=NB_CLASS)
```

I get the following error

> [image]

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Go to ~/.keras/models and remove the file that starts with mobilenet, and run your code again. It should download the weights file, make sure that the download completes.

Answer (score 0):

Without the save a'd the load file part of your code it's hard to say from where is the issue. If I well understood, you saved the weights in a file h5py?

I think it's always easier to save the whole trained model than only the weights:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem by deleting the pretrained weights and running the code again to redownload the file.

The pretrained weights file was saved in /home in the /.keras hidden folder in a .h5 file.